# Magento 2.2 - Custom WEBAPI - Custom JSON Structure

Tags: magento2, webapi

i need to understand following situation:

An external systems need to send a JSON Structure ( nearly similar than the magento default structure ) by using the web-api to import / update (POST/PULL) products.

The Structure differs to the default structure, cause the custom attributes are flat in the JSON and not in an array (custom_attributes).

So the default endpoint: (PUT) /rest/V1/products/:sku and the Interface for the method "save" \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface can not
understand the attributes.

Is it possible to reformat/normalize the JSON Structure before the Request reaches the initialisation of the \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface ?

I also try the solution to create a custom endpoint:

```
<route url="/V1/itc-api/products" method="PUT">
        <service class="Itc\Api\Api\ProductsManagementInterface" method="save"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

with a custom save Method:

```
public function save(\Itc\Api\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $saveOptions = false);
```

This Interface \Itc\Api\Api\Data\ProductInterface has all the flat get/set Methods like the custom JSON needs.

The Endpoint generally works, but magento throws an error:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Itc\Api\Api\Data\ProductInterface in /app/web/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50

I think the better way is, to reformat the structure and use the
original endpoint.

Thanks for help,
Andre

Comment: Your question itself has an answer `reformat the structure and use the original endpoint.` :-)

Comment: I know :) ;) --- But do you know the point where i can do this ( which method to overwrite with a plugin ? )